# Exponentiate (Multiply) Without ** (Python)

Tags: python, math, exponential

How can I perform this:

```
if p1 == 0:
    return 1
if p1 == 1:
    return temp_obj
if p1 == 2:
    return temp_obj*temp_obj
if p1 == 3:
    return temp_obj*temp_obj*temp_obj
if p1 == 4:
    return temp_obj*temp_obj*temp_obj*temp_obj
```

Without using **

I am actually writing this in a class that overloads **pow** and the ***** is already overloaded.

I tried

```
for x in range(p1):
  temp_obj = temp_obj * temp_obj
```

But that didn't work. The values were very high.

Thanks

Comment: you could use a recursive function.

Comment: @internet_user. not a bad idea, it does involve a bit more bookkeeping +1

Comment: couldn't you just rename `pow` before using that name for something else? Why reinvent the wheel to solve a namespace issue?

Comment: @JohnColeman. not very robust,  high likelihood of user error sooner or late

Comment: @ShpielMeister hiding a built-in isn't very robust either. Finding a way to resolve the name issue seems better than having to rewrite the functionality.

Comment: @MTG. did you mean ** is already overloaded

Comment: @ShpielMeiste My function that contains these if statements in the overloaded ** method.

Answer (score 6):

The reason this does not work is because you *square* the number for every value of the power. So that means that for `p1 = 3`, we get:

```
temp_obj = 5
temp_obj = temp_obj * temp_obj = 25
temp_obj = temp_obj * temp_obj = 625
temp_obj = temp_obj * temp_obj = 390625
```

So you actually calculated *5<sup>2<sup>3</sup></sup>*. So *5<sup>8</sup> = 390'625*.

We can solve this by each time multiplying with the value, so:

```
def power(x, p):
    if not p:
        return 1
    y = x
    for x in range(p-1):
        y *= x
    return y
```

But this works in linear time, we can also construct an algorithm in logarithmic time:

```
def power(x, p):
    if p == 0:
        return 1
    elif p & 1:
        return x * power(x*x, p//2)
    else:
        return power(x*x, p//2)
```

Or if we want to reduce the overhead of the recursive calls, an imperative version:

```
def power(x, p):
    r = 1
    while p:
        if p & 1:
            r *= x
        x *= x
        p >>= 1
    return r
```

For example:

```
>>> power(5, 6)
15625
>>> power(5, 1)
5
>>> power(5, 0)
1
>>> power(3, 2)
9
>>> power(3, 7)
2187
```

Comment: I called power(temp_obj, p1) but my return is 0 for some reason.

Comment: @MTG: with what parameters?

Comment: temp_obj is my initialized dictionary object and p1 is an int.

Comment: @MTG: initialized dictionary? You can not calculate the power of a dictionary. I tested it with some values (see edited answer).

Comment: But it works if I multiply out...temp_obj * temp_obj.... (I overloaded * and created my own to multiply dicts)

Comment: @MTG: are you sure that the operator you introduced is associative, commutative, etc. (like usually a numerical multiplication is)? In case it is not, the linear variant should still work.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming multiplication is associative, you can use exponentiation by squaring (`O(log n)`):

```
def pow(obj, num):
  res = 1  # assuming 1 is the identity
  while num:
    num, mul = divmod(num, 2)
    if mul:
      res *= obj
    obj *= obj
  return res
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt does not work because as you modify `temp_obj`, you cease to multiply it by its original value. You could also try the following:

```
initial_value = temp_obj
for x in range(p1):
  temp_obj = temp_obj * initial_value
```

Comment: OP says that the numbers are very big. `math.pow()` overflows easily.

Comment: Just gave this a try but it didn't work. The temp_obj * temp_obj are dictionaries that I already overloaded prior. My results are very large compared to what I want.